# Send later - mail

Tags: mail.app

It’s nice to see the send later function has finally come to the native mail app across all Apple systems.

Just curious how does it work under the hood?
For example, for a mail scheduled in a slot when my Mac is fully shut down, would it still be working properly?

Comment: Have you tried what happens in such cases?